# Displaying a number in Indian format using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, number-systems

I have the following code to display in Indian numbering system.

```
 var x=125465778;
 var res= x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
```

Am getting this output :`125,465,778`.

I need output like this: `12,54,65,778`.

Please help me to sort out this  problem .

Comment: What's the logic of the desired output ? One comma every 2 digits apart at the end ?

Comment: yes, It is indian numbering system

Comment: Can it have decimal point in it ?

Comment: what about 100 crore and 1000 crore.. anybody with a solution for that?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

For Integers:

```js
    var x=12345678;
    x=x.toString();
    var lastThree = x.substring(x.length-3);
    var otherNumbers = x.substring(0,x.length-3);
    if(otherNumbers != '')
        lastThree = ',' + lastThree;
    var res = otherNumbers.replace(/\B(?=(\d{2})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + lastThree;
    alert(res);
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XBtaw/)

For float:

```js
    var x=12345652457.557;
    x=x.toString();
    var afterPoint = '';
    if(x.indexOf('.') > 0)
       afterPoint = x.substring(x.indexOf('.'),x.length);
    x = Math.floor(x);
    x=x.toString();
    var lastThree = x.substring(x.length-3);
    var otherNumbers = x.substring(0,x.length-3);
    if(otherNumbers != '')
        lastThree = ',' + lastThree;
    var res = otherNumbers.replace(/\B(?=(\d{2})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + lastThree + afterPoint;
    
    alert(res);
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XBtaw/1/)

Comment: your answer returns `-,123` when the input number is `-123`

Comment: it returns 1,23,45,67,89,01,234.154 when I input 12345678901234.155

Comment: it returns -32,651.75 when passing -32650.75

Answer (score 111):

i'm late but i guess this will help :)

you can use [Number.prototype.toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)

Syntax

```
numObj.toLocaleString([locales [, options]])
```

```js
var number = 123456.789;
// India uses thousands/lakh/crore separators
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = number.toLocaleString('en-IN');
// → 1,23,456.789

document.getElementById('result1').innerHTML = number.toLocaleString('en-IN', {
    maximumFractionDigits: 2,
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'INR'
});
// → ₹1,23,456.79
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
<div id="result1"></div>
```

Comment: excellent. I didn't know such standard existed and with a good browser support.

Comment: If your value is in string i.e. "123456.789" make sure to convert this to number before calling. i.e. Number(number).toLocaleString('en-IN')

Answer (score 30):

Simple way to do,

**1. Direct Method using LocalString()**

```
(1000.03).toLocaleString()
(1000.03).toLocaleString('en-IN') # number followed by method
```

**2. using Intl - Internationalization API**

**The Intl** object is the namespace for the ECMAScript Internationalization API, which provides language sensitive string comparison, number formatting, and date and time formatting.

eg: `Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN').format(1000)`

**3. Using Custom Function:**

```js
function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toString().split('.')[0].length > 3 ? x.toString().substring(0,x.toString().split('.')[0].length-3).replace(/\B(?=(\d{2})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + "," + x.toString().substring(x.toString().split('.')[0].length-3): x.toString();
}

console.log("0 in indian format", numberWithCommas(0));
console.log("10 in indian format", numberWithCommas(10));
console.log("1000.15 in indian format", numberWithCommas(1000.15));
console.log("15123.32 in indian format", numberWithCommas(15123.32));
```

if your input is  10000.5,

```
numberWithCommas(10000.5)
```

You will get output like this, `10,000.5`

Comment: Your answer may help for me. but fine tune your answer as most faster and performance well

Comment: Incomplete solution |XXX|  numberWithCommas(12345.32) = > "1,23,45,.32"   |XXX|  
numberWithCommas(12345222.32) => "12,34,52,22,.32" |XXX|  numberWithCommas(45.32)  => "45,.32" |XXX| 
numberWithCommas(45) => ",45"

Comment: Kudos to Solution Number 2. I am going to use it for all my development.

Answer (score 25):

For integers only no additional manipulations needed.

This will match every digit from the end, having 1 or more double digits pattern after, and replace it with itself + ",":

```
"125465778".replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d)+$)/g, "$1,");
-> "1,25,46,57,78"
```

But since we want to have 3 in the end, let's state this explicitly by adding extra "\d" before match end of input:

```
"125465778".replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d)+\d$)/g, "$1,");
-> "12,54,65,778"
```

Answer (score 9):

Given a number to below function, it returns formatted number in Indian format of digit grouping.

> ex: input: 12345678567545.122343
>
> output: 1,23,45,67,85,67,545.122343

```js
    function formatNumber(num) {
            input = num;
            var n1, n2;
            num = num + '' || '';
            // works for integer and floating as well
            n1 = num.split('.');
            n2 = n1[1] || null;
            n1 = n1[0].replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d)+\d$)/g, "$1,");
            num = n2 ? n1 + '.' + n2 : n1;
            console.log("Input:",input)
            console.log("Output:",num)
            return num;
    }
    
    formatNumber(prompt("Enter Number",1234567))
```

https://jsfiddle.net/scLtnug8/1/

Answer (score 8):

I am little late in the game.
But here is the implicit way to do this.

```
var number = 3493423.34;

console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', { style: "currency", currency: "INR" }).format(number));
```

if you dont want currency symbol, use it like this

```
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN').format(number));
```

Comment: to use it in react-native, simply install a polyfill of intl and boom, good to go

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is just to use [Globalize](https://github.com/jquery/globalize) plugin (read more about it [here](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/39118647/Globalize) and [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/10/jquery-globalization-plugin-from-microsoft.aspx)):

```
var value = 125465778;
var formattedValue = Globalize.format(value, 'n');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like below, I have found a number formatter Plugin here : [Java script number Formatter](http://code.google.com/p/javascript-number-formatter/)

By using that i have done the below code, It works fine, Try this, It will help you..

**SCRIPT :**

```
<script src="format.20110630-1100.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
  var FullData = format( "#,##0.####", 125465778)
  var n=FullData.split(",");
  var part1 ="";
    for(i=0;i<n.length-1;i++)
    part1 +=n[i];
  var part2 = n[n.length-1]
  alert(format( "#0,#0.####", part1) + "," + part2);
</script>
```

**Inputs :**

```
1) 125465778
2) 1234567.89
```

**Outputs :**

```
1) 12,54,65,778
2) 12,34,567.89
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use https://osrec.github.io/currencyFormatter.js/

Then all you need is:

```
OSREC.CurrencyFormatter.format(2534234, { currency: 'INR' }); 
// Returns ₹ 25,34,234.00
```

Answer (score 2):

**These will format the value in the respective systems.**

```
$(this).replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',');
```

> For US number system (millions & billions)

```
$(this).replace(/\B(?=(?:(\d\d)+(\d)(?!\d))+(?!\d))/g, ',');
```

> For Indian number system (lakhs & crores)

Answer (score 1):

This function can handle float value properly just addition to another answer

```
function convertNumber(num) {
  var n1, n2;
  num = num + '' || '';
  n1 = num.split('.');
  n2 = n1[1] || null;
  n1 = n1[0].replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d)+\d$)/g, "$1,");   
  num = n2 ? n1 + '.' + n2 : n1;
  n1 = num.split('.');
  n2 = (n1[1]) || null;
  if (n2 !== null) {
           if (n2.length <= 1) {
                   n2 = n2 + '0';
           } else {
                   n2 = n2.substring(0, 2);
           }
   }
   num = n2 ? n1[0] + '.' + n2 : n1[0];

   return num;
}
```

this function will convert all function to float as it is

```
function formatAndConvertToFloatFormat(num) {
  var n1, n2;
  num = num + '' || '';
  n1 = num.split('.');
  if (n1[1] != null){
    if (n1[1] <= 9) {
       n2 = n1[1]+'0';
    } else {
       n2 = n1[1]
    }
  } else {
     n2 = '00';
  }
  n1 = n1[0].replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d)+\d$)/g, "$1,");
  return  n1 + '.' + n2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Improvised Slopen's approach above, Works for both int and floats.

```js
 
 
 function getIndianFormat(str) { 
  str = str.split(".");
  return str[0].replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d)+\d$)/g, "$1,") + (str[1] ? ("."+str[1]): "");
 }
     
 console.log(getIndianFormat("43983434")); //4,39,83,434
 console.log(getIndianFormat("1432434.474")); //14,32,434.474
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Nidhinkumar's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46376397/indian-currency-format-is-not-working-in-html) i have checked the above answers and
while handling negative numbers the output won't be correct for eg: -300 it should display as -300 but the above answers will display it as -,300 which is not good so i have tried with the below code which works even during the negative cases.

```
var negative = input < 0;
    var str = negative ? String(-input) : String(input);
    var arr = [];
    var i = str.indexOf('.');
    if (i === -1) {
      i = str.length;
    } else {
      for (var j = str.length - 1; j > i; j--) {
        arr.push(str[j]);
      }
      arr.push('.');
    }
    i--;
    for (var n = 0; i >= 0; i--, n++) {
      if (n > 2 && (n % 2 === 1)) {
        arr.push(',');
      }
      arr.push(str[i]);
    }
    if (negative) {
      arr.push('-');
    }
    return arr.reverse().join('');
```

Answer (score 0):

Indian money format function

```js
   function indian_money_format(amt)
     {  
      amt=amt.toString();
      var lastThree = amt.substring(amt.length-3);
      var otherNumbers = amt.substring(0,amt.length-3);
      if(otherNumbers != '')
       lastThree = ',' + lastThree;
      var result = otherNumbers.replace(/\B(?=(\d{2})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + lastThree;
        alert(result)
      return result;
     }
      
      indian_money_format(prompt("Entry amount",123456))
```

Answer (score 0):

Improvising @slopen's answer with decimal support and test cases.

**Usage**: `numberToIndianFormat(555555.12) === "5,55,555.12"`

`utils.ts`

```
export function numberToIndianFormat(x: number): string {
    if (isNaN(x)) {
        return "NaN"
    } else {
        let string = x.toString();
        let numbers = string.split(".");
        numbers[0] = integerToIndianFormat(parseInt(numbers[0]))
        return numbers.join(".");
    }
}
function integerToIndianFormat(x: number): string {
    if (isNaN(x)) {
        return "NaN"
    } else {
        let integer = x.toString();
        if (integer.length > 3) {
            return integer.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d)+\d$)/g, "$1,");
        } else {
            return integer;
        }
    }
}
```

`utils.spec.ts`

```
describe('numberToIndianFormat', () => {
    it('nan should output NaN', () => {
        expect(numberToIndianFormat(Number.NaN)).toEqual("NaN")
    });
    describe('pure integer', () => {
        it('should leave zero untouched', () => {
            expect(numberToIndianFormat(0)).toEqual("0")
        });
        it('should leave simple numbers untouched', () => {
            expect(numberToIndianFormat(10)).toEqual("10")
        });
        it('should add comma at thousand place', () => {
            expect(numberToIndianFormat(5555)).toEqual("5,555")
        });
        it('should add comma at lakh place', () => {
            expect(numberToIndianFormat(555555)).toEqual("5,55,555")
        });
        it('should add comma at crore place', () => {
            expect(numberToIndianFormat(55555555)).toEqual("5,55,55,555")
        });
    });
    describe('with fraction', () => {
        it('should leave zero untouched', () => {
            expect(numberToIndianFormat(0.12)).toEqual("0.12")
        });
        it('should leave simple numbers untouched', () => {
            expect(numberToIndianFormat(10.12)).toEqual("10.12")
        });
        it('should add comma at thousand place', () => {
            expect(numberToIndianFormat(5555.12)).toEqual("5,555.12")
        });
        it('should add comma at lakh place', () => {
            expect(numberToIndianFormat(555555.12)).toEqual("5,55,555.12")
        });
        it('should add comma at crore place', () => {
            expect(numberToIndianFormat(55555555.12)).toEqual("5,55,55,555.12")
        });
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Intl.NumberFormat for formatting numbers to Indian format. Here is an Example below:

```
const number = 12345678;

const formatedNumber = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', { style: 'currency', currency: 'INR' }).format(number);

console.log(formatedNumber)
// Expected output: "₹1,23,45,678.00"
```

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat)

Comment: There are already multiple answers saying that, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54547602/7264739

Answer (score 0):

In some cases where padding of additional 0's are necessary even though the number is a whole number, you can add the minimumFractionDigits: 2 option to set minimum 2 digits.

```
let price = 784000;
let cost = 12750000.5

price.toLocaleString('en-IN');
cost.toLocaleString('en-IN');

//price → 7,84,000
//cost → 1,27,50,000.5

price.toLocaleString('en-IN', {
  minimumFractionDigits: 2,
  maximumFractionDigits: 2
});
cost.toLocaleString('en-IN', {
  minimumFractionDigits: 2,
  maximumFractionDigits: 2
});
//price → 7,84,000.00
//cost → 1,27,50,000.50
```