# Angular2 :: Javascript :: Currency formatting :: PKR 12,34,56,789/-

Tags: javascript, angular

Whereas usually a large currency value like `USD 123456789` is formatted as `USD 123,456,789`, here in Pakistan, such a number is formatted as `Rs. 12,34,56,789/-` (last 3 digits grouped, then every 2 digits grouped together, the entire string followed by a `/-`.

Is it possible to use the default Angular `Currency` pipe to achieve this? If not, what's the correct regex that I can use to achieve this formatting in my custom pipe's `transform` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching more around SO, I found this post which addresses the same problem:

[Displaying a number in Indian format using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16037165/displaying-a-number-in-indian-format-using-javascript)

The relevant code snippet is this:

```
let amount = value.toString();
var lastThree = amount.substring(amount.length - 3);
var otherNumbers = amount.substring(0, amount.length - 3);
if(otherNumbers != '') lastThree = ',' + lastThree;
var result = otherNumbers.replace(/\B(?=(\d{2})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + lastThree;
```

This works fine for my case as well.. =)