# how to change number format based on locale

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

In Angular 8, i need to convert number text based on language selected.
For example 123456789 number in **US** format **123,456,456** when converted to **indian** format it will be **12,34,56,456**

It need to be dynamically change based on language selected.

It need to support any language or any currency.

Comment: Would this be what you're looking for: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Displaying a number in Indian format using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16037165/displaying-a-number-in-indian-format-using-javascript)

Comment: @K41F4r thanks for the solution is there any option to convert back to orginal number. Thanks in advance

Comment: You could save the original number separately and convert it to the requested language for display purposes when needed. You probably shouldn't modify the original number itself

Comment: In UI number is editable, if i change number in UI i don't know the updated number